# How to access tag attributes (params) using React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have two React components - MyMenu and MyMenuItem. MyMenu corresponds to a list of items in my state (using Redux to propagate changes to the items or the list). MyMenuItem should render a specific item from that list...so MyMenu needs to pass an identifier to MyMenuItem so it knows which item to render.

For example, the render function in MyMenu would roughly look like:

```
  const menu_items = [];
  items.forEach(function(item)
    { menu_items.push(<MyMenuItem item_id={item.id} /> }
  return (<div><ul> {menu_items} </ul><div>);
```

The MyMenuItem component looks like:

```
const MyMenuItem = ({app_state}) =>
    {
    let id = item_id;
    let link = "/testresult/" + id;
    let name = app_state.items[id].name;

    return ( <li key={id}><Link href={link}>{name}</Link> </li> );
    };
```

To declare the required item_id parameter, it would have:

```
MyMenuItem.propTypes =
    { item_id: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired };
```

And to connect to the app state from the Redux store, it would have something like:

```
export default connect(state =>
    ({ app_state: state.AppState }))(MyMenuItem);
```

In the above example, item_id will be undefined. What I can't figure out is how to get access to the params, or specifically the item_id param that is passed to the component. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are "connecting" a component that is too granular. Of course you can connect whichever component you'd like, but consider "connecting" an outer component like the "page".

In your specific case, if you "connect" the `MyMenu` you wouldn't have the problem you described.

Something like this:

```
const menu_items = [];
  app_state.items.forEach(function(item)
    { menu_items.push(<MyMenuItem item={item} /> }
  return (<div><ul> {menu_items} </ul><div>);
```

Notice that the above can be replaced by:

```
return <div><ul>
{ app_state.items.map((item, index) => <MyMenuItem item={item} key={index}} />
</ul></div>;
```

Now your `MyMenuItem` would be something like:

```
const MyMenuItem = ({item}) =>
    {
    let id = item.id;
    let link = "/testresult/" + id;
    let name = item.name;

    return ( <li key={id}><Link href={link}>{name}</Link> </li> );
    };
```

### Answering your original question

Redux's `connect` creates a HOC (another component that is a wrapper of your original component) that automatically binds props to the state using the `mapStateToProps` function.

**Can I pass additional props to the HOC component by "connect"?**

Yes, but I'm pretty sure you have to pass the `mergeProps` argument for that. Take a look at the [connect documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options). The third argument is a function like:

```
mergeProps(stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) { /* return resulting props */ }
```

This function is supposed to, obviously, get the objects returned from `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps` and the component's own props and return a resulting object which fields will be the props of the `connected` component.

**Is this a best practice?**

I'm sure there are legit use cases for this, but I have never needed this in my life. What people normally do is to `connect` only the outer component or components, like the page component. If you have some sort of "master page", you can connect the "master page" for the app header and each individual page.

The philosophy behind Redux is that, if you need to change anything in the page, you should trigger actions, that change the global store, that, in turns, re-renders the connected components. Of course there are optimizations to prevent unnecessary rerenders.

Comment: Thanks, @andrerpena! Your example made me realize I was working under a bad assumption. Because the JSX format looks like HTML, I was thinking in that format and assumed I could not pass entire objects - only values that can be represented as simple strings. Once I got that out of my head, your suggestion solves my immediate problem. But for the original question - how to have access to both the redux store/state (via connect) AND props (passed from a parent) - is that possible? (without some ugly hack). Would it be an anti-pattern?

Comment: @CMerrill, I'm glad I could help. I've updated the answer to try to answer your question.